# Create API for MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

I have two websites which I'm going to call here `mywebsite1.com` which has a MySQL Database and `mywebsite2.com` which does **not** have a MySQL Database and both with PHP.

I need a database in `mywebsite2.com`, so I wanted to use the database from `mywebsite1.com`. My problem is "how do I do that?". It's easy to save data to the database, just send it as `$_GET[]` data and do a query.

The problem is to read data from the database. What are my solutions? Is there any API already made? Should I output the data has an XML file ? I'd like to hear some solutions with pros and cons.

I have no possibility of buying an MySQL service for `mywebsite2.com`, so please don't suggest that. This are the resources I have, so only use this in your answers OR other **free** solutions.

Comment: Yes, an API would be a good way to go. You'll need to check on your second site whether you can contact the first site - try a `file_get_contents('http://mywebsite1.com/')` to see if you can read the home page. Many free hosts block this sort of thing, and if it's blocked, you'll need to see if they will change the rules for you first before you put effort into writing an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have access to your MySQL database from your second site. Easily.

If it has cPanel you have to enable Remote MySQL option and add the IP of your second site so that connections from it will be trusted!

Then you can access it directly from the second site.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/RemoteMySQL

In your case that you have a free host, You can use [Xeround](http://www.xeround.com) which provides free mysql databases in the cloud!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that, because the database if from a free host, so I don't have access to that

Comment: so another solution will be [Xeround](http://www.xeround.com).. Provides free database solutions!

Comment: Xeround looks like a very good solution, I'll take a look :)

Comment: The free plan only allows 10MB, not sure if it is enough..

Comment: Well that's the only cloud I found that gives out free databases.

Comment: And see 10MB in a database is far too much! when it comes to storing text values which size hardly goes bigger than a few bytes!

Comment: @Miguel: the cost of offering (database) hosting is _always_ non-zero, so if you are creating a useful service that incurs costs to someone else, there comes a point where one ought to pay for the service. Sadly, this holds true even if you are not making money out of the enterprise yourself `:-)`.

Comment: 10MB would be enough if this app didn't need to save text in the database. It will work with rss feeds and I need to save the messages! Maybe I'll use this 10MB database for some parts of the app and save the rss feed in my `website1.com` database, and output them as xml with an API

Answer (score 0):

An option for you, as you say you can't use RemoteMySQL, might be using a http request via php.

E.g.:

```
$request = new HttpRequest("mywebsite1.com");
$request->addQueryData(array("getparam_name"=>"getparam_value"));
$response = new HttpMessage($request->send());
$responseText = $response->getBody();
```

Thats a bit like reinventing the wheel though.
(You'll have to parse your response data somehow ...)

For detailed information on Http-Requests with PHP take a look at [php.net->HTTP](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.http.php)

Hope that might help you ;)